# Bootstrap 3 Upgrade to Bootstrap 5 NavBar Issue

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-5, web-frontend

I am responsible for upgrading Bootstrap from 3 to 5, and allow some minor UI changes, like px-wise changes. However I am suffering from navbar transition like the below discussed.

Here is the simplified version of my navbar using Bootstrap 3.

```css
.image-header-logo {
  margin: -5px;
  height: 34px;
}

.custom-navbar {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px rgb(255 100 0);
}

.navbar {
  border: 0px;
}

.navbar-nav > li.active {
  box-shadow: inset 0px -5px 0px 0px rgba(255, 119, 0, 0.68);
}

.navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #ff6633;
}

.navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
    background: rgb(255, 119, 0);
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<nav class="navbar custom-navbar">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
              <img class="image-header-logo" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e8bf61002bf07be4ca6085c301f990c0?s=64" />
      </a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" >
                <li><a class="nav-menu-item">Welcome</a></li>
                <li class="active">
          <a class="nav-selected-menu-item nav-text-color" href="#">Java</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="nav-selected-menu-item nav-text-color" href="#">PHP</a>
        </li>
            </ul>   
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

And here is the new code using Bootstrap 5.

```css
body {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
}

.image-header-logo {
  height: 2.5rem;
}

.navbar {
  padding: 0 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}

.custom-navbar {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px rgb(255 100 0);
}

.nav-item {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0.5rem 0;
}

.navbar .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav .nav-item.active {
  box-shadow: inset 0px -5px 0px 0px rgba(255, 119, 0, 0.68);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navbar .navbar-collapse > .navbar-text,
.navbar .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav .nav-item > .nav-link {
  color: #ff6633;
}

.navbar .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav .nav-item:hover {
    background: rgb(255, 119, 0);
    color: #ffffff; /* FIXME: not work == */
}

/* FIXME:  need to add this, but in the outskirt it does not work */
.navbar .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav .nav-item > .nav-link:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light custom-navbar">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="/i/trade">
    <img class="image-header-logo" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e8bf61002bf07be4ca6085c301f990c0?s=64" />
  </a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#myNavbar">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
    <span class="navbar-text ms-auto">Welcome</span>
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active px-1">
        <a class="nav-link">Java</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item px-1">
        <a class="nav-link">PHP</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

> As it seems there is a rendering issue in stackoverflow, I have also place the code in jsfiddle.
> The same codebase can also be found in jsfiddle.
>
> Bootstrap 3: https://jsfiddle.net/hphchan/hfo9njc3/66/
>
> Bootstrap 5: https://jsfiddle.net/hphchan/4yrxu8dk/60/

Most of the UI generated from the 2 version looks similar, but with the below issue.

> When hover on `nav-item` but not `nav-link` in Bootstrap 5, as there is a padding in nav-item, making the hover color changes not work.
> which can be seen in the picture below.
>
> [image: hover_not_working_in_bootstrap_5]
>
> And here is the Bootstrap 3 version, which works in the edge.
> [image: hover_work_in_bootstrap_3]

I understand why it does not work due to the class structure change. However what I do not know is how to make the hover behavior the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can emulate the behavior using the hover selector only for the **nav-link** class and forgetting the nav-item to simplify what style applies when hovered.
This way **nav-link** should have color: #ff6633 when not hovered and color: #ffffff when hovered:

```css
.navbar .navbar-collapse>.navbar-text,
.navbar .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav .nav-item>.nav-link {
  color: #ff6633;
}

.navbar .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav .nav-item>.nav-link:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  background: rgb(255, 119, 0);
}
```

Also, remove the ** margin-bottom ** property for the .navbar.

The markup for the ul would be:

```html
<ul class="navbar-nav">
  <li class="nav-item active mx-2">
    <a class="nav-link py-3 px-3">Java</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item ms-2">
    <a class="nav-link py-3 px-3">PHP</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Working example:

```css
body {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.image-header-logo {
  height: 2.5rem;
}

.navbar {
  padding: 0 1rem;
  /* override default 0.5rem 1rem */
  /* box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px rgb(255, 100, 0); */
  /* TODO: placed in #header instead */
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  /* reserve space for the box-shadow */
}

.custom-navbar {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px rgb(255 100 0);
}

/* to create sadow on the bottom */
.nav-item {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navbar .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav .nav-item.active>.nav-link {
  box-shadow: inset 0px -5px 0px 0px rgba(255, 119, 0, 0.68);
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* to show orange in color on the line */
/* need to specify for so long, so that it can win without use of !important... == */
.navbar .navbar-collapse>.navbar-text,
.navbar .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav .nav-item>.nav-link {
  color: #ff6633;
}

/* FIXME:  need to add this, but in the outskirt it does not work */
.navbar .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav .nav-item>.nav-link:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  background: rgb(255, 119, 0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light custom-navbar py-0">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="/i/trade">
    <img class="image-header-logo" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e8bf61002bf07be4ca6085c301f990c0?s=64" />
  </a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#myNavbar">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
    <span class="navbar-text ms-auto">Welcome</span>
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active mx-2">
        <a class="nav-link py-3 px-3">Java</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item ms-2">
        <a class="nav-link py-3 px-3">PHP</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```